# @ContentChildren is not being populated

Tags: angular

I have three components: App, Parent, and Child:

**App Component**

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    directives: [Parent,Child],
    template: '<parent><child>hi</child><child>there</child></parent>'
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor() {
    }
}
```

**Parent Component**

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    template: '<div><h1>Parent</h1><ng-content></ng-content></div>'
})
export class Parent {
    @ContentChildren(Child) children: QueryList<Child>;
    ngAfterContentInit() {
        console.log(this.children);
    }
}
```

**Child Component**

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    template: '<div><h1>Child</h1></div>'
})
export class Child {
}
```

As you can see in the Parent component, I've tried to use `@ContentChildren` to get the list of Child components, using the `Child` type as a selector.  However, this does not seem to work - the content children list is always undefined.

In the `ngAfterContentInit()` method, I would have expected content children to be populated.

Am I missing something?

**[Update]**

So it turns out that the problem exists when all three components are in the same file (see console debug window where I output the content children):

[Plnkr Demo of Issue](http://plnkr.co/edit/57GCqrsO8xC5gntvDuxd?p=preview)

If they are in separate files the problem goes away:

[Plnkr Demo Working](http://plnkr.co/edit/jEwtG5jFbeId0D5RWLrf?p=preview)

Normally, I would only place all the components in the same file for learning purposes.  But it has me curious. Does anyone know why the behaviour is different?

Comment: The children are visible in the DOM? I just tried it (in Dart) and it's working. Have you tried a more permissive type than `QueryList<Child>` for the variable like `any`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I tried changing the type to any but the problem is still there.  It seems its related to all three components being in the same file.

Comment: I can't reproduce in Dart (if this is any help), it also works with everything in one file.

Comment: it is:). I've tried it in plnkr and VS2015 and its same issue... strange

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to use [forwardRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/forwardRef-function.html)  to reference classes which are not yet defined. See [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/6V3IjNFjHbvjFSe9xdGQ?p=preview). Remember [ES6 classes are not hoisted](http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html#class_declarations_are_not_hoisted).

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    template: '<div><h1>Parent</h1><ng-content></ng-content></div>'
})
export class Parent {
    @ContentChildren(forwardRef(() => Child)) children; // <!- HERE

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        console.log(this.children);
        console.log(this.children.length);
    }
}
```

**UPD** Mark Rajcok pointed out an excellent article about forward references in angular2 (see the comment bellow). Must read: [thoughtram.io Forward references in Angular 2](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/03/forward-references-in-angular-2.html).

Comment: +1, beat me to the post. OP, note that just [declaring `Child` before `Parent`](http://plnkr.co/edit/64OJMwOwEle6wNycwwDz?p=preview) in the same file also works.

Comment: Just FYI, the use of `forwardRef()` is mentioned in the [Dependency Injection dev guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html), near the bottom of the page, in the "Appendix: Why we recommend one class per file" section.  The guide also recommends reading [this blog post](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/03/forward-references-in-angular-2.html) for more info about when to use `forwardRef()`.

Comment: @MarkRajcok Thank you for the thoughtram post. I've added link to the answer.

Comment: Even this doens't work for me :/ 

@ContentChildren(forwardRef(() => DraggableDialogBaseComponent),{ descendants: true }) child: DraggableDialogBaseComponent[];

I'm checking in AfterContentInit and the list is empty

Answer (score 16):

You need to add `{ descendants: true }` to include nested children,

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    template: '<div><h1>Parent</h1><ng-content></ng-content></div>'
})
export class Parent {
    @ContentChildren(Child, { descendants: true }) children: QueryList<Child>;
    ngAfterContentInit() {
        console.log(this.children);
        console.log(this.children.length);
    }
}
```

> [descendants](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren) - True to include all descendants, otherwise include only
>   direct children.

Answer (score 1):

This also happens if your child component references your parent component in the constructor; Angular doesn't like the circular reference!

I needed to choose only one method for parent->child communication: either use `ContentChildren` OR use the parent component in the child's `constructor`.

```
@Component()
export class Parent {
  @ContentChildren(Child)
  private children: QueryList<Child>;
}

@Component()
export class Child {
  constructor(
    // !! Remove the following line to make the ContentChildren "work" again.
    @Optional() parent: Parent
  ) { }
}
```